# Building unread_message counter ends in resource id error

Tags: php, sql

Trying to get the unread messages from my database with this function, but I end in resource id errors like this one: "`Resource id #45`"

```
function unread_message_count() {
    $sql = "SELECT conversations_messages.message_id, conversations_members.user_id,             conversations_members.conversation_last_view, conversations_messages.message_date 
            FROM conversations_members 
            INNER JOIN conversations_messages ON conversations_messages.user_id = conversations_members.user_id 
            WHERE conversations_members.conversation_last_view < conversations_messages.message_date AND conversations_members.user_id =     {$_SESSION['user_id']}";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            return $result;
}
```

I call the function this way, but to nothing prints:

```
$count = unread_message_count();
echo $count;
```

Comment: show your error message as it is

Comment: updated error message

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns a resource on success, or `FALSE` on error, you need to fetch the data from results, like:

```
...
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
return $rows;
```

Btw, mysql_ is deprecated, [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query()` returns a resource. The *to string* (implicitly triggered by using `echo` to output it) of that is *Resource ID #* followed by the id.

A resource in PHP is only supposed to be used with other PHP functions. This includes but is not limited to file, curl, ftp handles, etc.

use `mysql_fetch_array()` (or similar)

Just Try this

```
function unread_message_count() {
    $sql = "SELECT conversations_messages.message_id, conversations_members.user_id,             conversations_members.conversation_last_view, conversations_messages.message_date 
            FROM conversations_members 
            INNER JOIN conversations_messages ON conversations_messages.user_id = conversations_members.user_id 
            WHERE conversations_members.conversation_last_view < conversations_messages.message_date AND conversations_members.user_id =     {$_SESSION['user_id']}";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            $data = mysql_num_rows($result);
            return $data;
}
```

Comment: thanks hossain. i'm currently calling the function this way: $count = unread_message_count(); echo $count;  is that how you would do it?

Comment: what is your expected output. like 20 or 30?